# nexus-cli returns 404 with command nexus-cli image ls

Tags: nexus

I'm trying to remove unused docker images from nexus repo using nexus-cli(with automation script).

I have downloaded nexus-cli and configured Host, Repository, Username and Password when I'm trying to hit command

`./nexus-cli image ls`

It retrns `HTTP Code: 404`
can anyone please help me on this or please suggest me if there is any another way to remove unused docker images

Refrance links: http://www.blog.labouardy.com/cleanup-old-docker-images-from-nexus-repository/
https://www.ivankrizsan.se/2016/06/09/create-a-private-docker-registry/#comment-739

Answer (score 0):

NXRM3 has a "Purge unused docker manifests and images" task that may be helpful.  It removes any items that are no longer associated as in use.  Unfortunately, because docker shares layers if the layers are used elsewhere this task often isn't as much help.  If you manually remove the images then it should remove the layers that are no longer used however.

Ref: https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM3/System+Configuration#SystemConfiguration-TypesofTasksandWhentoUseThem

Also don't forget to run the "Compact blob store" task after you run any NXRM3 cleanup task.  Otherwise, your files are just soft deleted and not freeing up any space.

You may also wish to watch https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-11435 and even provide feedback if you have specific usage scenarios.